# Split Dataframe and stack horizontally

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pivot, stack, transform

I have the following DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {
   "cat": ['A'] * 3 + ['B'] * 2,   
   "val1": [10, 9, 12, 20, 25],
   "val2": [1, 3, 2, 6, 7],
   "idx": [0, 1, 5, 1, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('idx', inplace=True)
```

which gives

```
      cat     val1   val2
idx         
0       A       10      1
1       A        9      3
5       A       12      2
1       B       20      6
2       B       25      7
```

I want to transform it into a DataFrame with a column MultiIndex

```
        A              B
     val1   val2    val1    val2
idx         
0      10      1      NA      NA
1       9      3      20       6
2      NA     NA      25       7
5      12      2      NA      NA
```

Is there a way to do this without manually splitting and horizontally concatenating the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with [`df.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), [`swaplevel`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html), and [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html). Add [`df.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) to get rid of the added column name (i.e. 'cat').

```py
out = (
    df.pivot(columns='cat')
    .swaplevel(0, 1, axis=1)
    .sort_index(axis=1, level=0)
    .rename_axis(columns=(None, None))
)

out

        A          B     
     val1 val2  val1 val2
idx                      
0    10.0  1.0   NaN  NaN
1     9.0  3.0  20.0  6.0
2     NaN  NaN  25.0  7.0
5    12.0  2.0   NaN  NaN
```

If `idx` is not yet your *index* from the start, you can skip `df.set_index('idx', inplace=True)` and simply use: `df.pivot(index='idx', columns='cat')`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
   "cat": ['A'] * 3 + ['B'] * 2,   
   "val1": [10, 9, 12, 20, 25],
   "val2": [1, 3, 2, 6, 7],
   "idx": [0, 1, 5, 1, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('idx', inplace=True)

pivot_df = df.pivot_table(index=df.index, columns='cat', aggfunc='first')

pivot_df.columns = [' '.join(col).strip() for col in pivot_df.columns.values]

print(pivot_df)
```

Output will be like that

```
     val1 A  val1 B  val2 A  val2 B
idx
0      10.0     NaN     1.0     NaN
1       9.0    20.0     3.0     6.0
2       NaN    25.0     NaN     7.0
5      12.0     NaN     2.0     NaN
```